# Polymer 1.0 <paper-toast> appears behind <paper-drawer-panel>

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

I am using the Polymer Starter Kit.

When I add a `<paper-toast>` element, it appears behind the `<paper-drawer-panel>` when I `.show()` it.

Has anyone else had this problem and do you have any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced this same problem and figured out what's happening.

If you're doing the same thing as me, then you've got your `paper-toast` somewhere inside the `main` section of the `paper-drawer-panel`. In which case, move the `paper-toast` outside the `paper-drawer-panel`.

**What worked for me** was adding my `paper-toast` in `index.html` just after the closing `</paper-drawer-panel>` tag.

In case you need to use a dynamic message (ie, the message content is determined in a custom element that's not available on `index.html` then you can set the text in your custom element as below.

---

**index.html**

```
<paper-drawer-panel>
    <!-- Your chest of drawers go here -->
</paper-drawer-panel>

<paper-toast id="somethingWentWrong"
             duration="6000">
</paper-toast>
```

**elsewhere.html**

```
<!-- Assuming of course that this is included in index.html -->
<p on-click="paragraphClicked">Click Me</p>


paragraphClicked: function() {
   var toast = document.querySelector('#somethingWentWrong');
   toast.text = 'Aaargh!';
   toast.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the z-index style of the paper-toast to a suitable value, like 10000. It even works with a paper-toast element inside a web component